# Win form app freezing upon launch

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox

Let me first confess that I am a fairly green programmer but I am in dire straits trying to figure out what is wrong with my application.

The goal so far is to make a timer kick off when the button is clicked and the elapsed time continually display on the text box.

There are probably better ways to implement this but humor me for a second and I practice creating events and using them in programs.

What I see happening when I launch the code is that it just freezes and never recovers, I need to end the app with the task manager.

Any pointers on what I may be doing wrong and how to fix it will be appreciated.

```
// see clock class below containing delegate and event instantiation

public class Clock
{
    public delegate void TimeChangedHandler(object clock, TimeEventArgs timeInfo);
    public TimeChangedHandler TimeChanged;

    public void RunClock()
    {
        TimeEventArgs e = new TimeEventArgs();//initialize args
        while (e.keepCounting)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            e.EndTime = DateTime.Now;

            if (e.StartTime != e.EndTime)
            {
                e.duration = e.EndTime.Subtract(e.StartTime);
            }

            if (TimeChanged != null)
            {
                TimeChanged(this, e);
            }


        }
    }


//see timeevent args description below:

public class TimeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public TimeSpan duration;
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public bool keepCounting = false;

    public TimeEventArgs()
    {
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        EndTime = DateTime.Now;
        keepCounting = true;
    }
}


//See form class below:

  public partial class TimeApp : Form
{


    public TimeApp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void startStopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var theClock = new Clock();
        var timeApp = new TimeApp();
        timeApp.Subscribe(theClock);
        theClock.RunClock();

    }

    public void Subscribe(Clock theClock)
    {
        theClock.TimeChanged += new Clock.TimeChangedHandler(NewTime);
    }

    public void NewTime(object theClock, TimeEventArgs e)
    {

        displayBox.Text = e.duration.Hours.ToString() + ":"
            + e.duration.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + e.duration.Seconds.ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: Probably look at using a BackgroundWorker http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker instead of events

Comment: You have an infinite loop. As such, your loop blocks the UI thread from processing messages from the operating system.

Comment: You should give your UI a chance to breathe. Try Application.DoEvents() every now and then in your loop to let the form repaint and process window messages.

Comment: @lrb That's a pretty awful way to make it work.  `Application.DoEvents()` is almost always a bad idea...

Comment: Standard mistake is to be a green programmer and just write code without the benefit of a book or tutorial.  Sure, it won't work.  You solve that by reading the book instead of asking somebody to read it for you.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead Without a doubt Application.DoEvents() is on the sketchy end of hacks. I was suggesting to the op a quick way to unfreeze his app. There are more elegant solutions, no doubt. I probably should have stated that up front.

Comment: @Irb Reed actually said that.. although I agree with him.

Comment: @HansPassant I have not asked you to read for me. Your contribution here was pretty useless.

Comment: I have not come across backgroundworker or Application.DoEvents and am educating myself now.
Many thanks for all the pointers -- I will work on fixing the code and update the question with corrected code when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RunClock` method blocks the UI (because of the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` call), which makes it impossible to stop.

Instead of looping, you should look at adding a `Windows.Forms.Timer` to your form, and using it to drive the clock.

Comment: This along with @failedprogramming 's link showed me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are suspending your main (UI) thread when calling `Thread.Sleep(1000)` - which is why your app is non-responsive.

Use a `Timer` (instead of `Thread.Sleep()`) and spin off any processing/long running code to a `BackgroundWorker` with  for any processing you need to do. That way, your UI will stay responsive.